# How to declare types for a third party library locally which has a hyphenated name?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

My code uses the "react-social-sharing" library and I'm migrating from JavaScript to TypeScript. It doesn't appear to have any types associated with it so I tried declaring it locally, but I can't get it to import correctly.

I was following the steps outlined here: https://www.detroitlabs.com/blog/adding-custom-type-definitions-to-a-third-party-library/

1. I created a "local-types" folder with a "react-social-sharing" subfolder.
2. I added an index.d.ts file
3. I added typeRoots, paths, and exclude to my tsconfig
4. I tried declaring the module in the index.d.ts file, but I can't get it to export with the hyphenated name

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "typeRoots":["src/local-types"]
  },
  "paths":{
    "react-social-sharing": ["./src/local-types/react-social-sharing"]
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["src/local-types/**"]
}
```

I've tried other variations of using module and namespace in the index.d.ts, but no luck so far.

Any help would be appreciated

My src/local-types/react-social-sharing/index.d.ts file:

[image: screenshot of error in my index.d.ts]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the proper way for declaring a module is like this:

```
declare module 'react-social-sharing' {
  export type Facebook = JSX.Element;
   ...
}
```